Cannot Find referance DeutschJozsa in __init__.py
I am new to quantum computing and Python. I tried to make a quantum simulation with qiskit, but I have some import issues that I can't solve, and I decided to ask it here.
I tried to import DeutschJozsa , aer and AerProvider, but it gives an error all the time.
Here is the code :
import numpy as np
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, Aer, transpile, assemble, execute
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram
from qiskit.algorithms import Grover, DeutschJozsa
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
from qiskit.providers.aer import AerProvider

I get those errors in lines 5,6,7. Here are the errors:
Cannot find reference 'DeutschJozsa' in '__init__.py'
Cannot find reference 'aer' in '__init__.py'
Unresolved reference 'AerProvider'

How can I fix these errors?

It seems you are using an older version of Qiskit. First off, the qiskit.algorithms module is no longer part of Qiskit. It is now a package on its own that you would have to install separately. Furthermore, the DeutschJosza function no longer exists, so it is going to be a bit hard for you to find help fixing this issue. The only solution might be to install exactly the version of qiskit that has this function working with no errors, which is hard to hunt down.

Due to some documentation changes to Qiskit a lot of imports have changed and or have been deprecated. Below I show how to import Aer properly.
import numpy as np
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile, assemble, execute
from qiskit_aer import Aer  # This is the new way to import Aer
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram

As for the algortihms, qiskit no longer has direct imports for these but they have made documentation for a new way to implement Grovers Algorithm, Grover's algorithm.
For DeutschJozsa there are many outside references to help create your own function/oracle, but this is one I think is useful not only in understanding how to create your oracle but how to use it as well, DeutschJozsa algorithm.
Similar case for AerProvider, this import no longer exists so I recommend looking into the new documentation for the Qiskit providers and using the one that best matches what you need qiskit.providers.
